# Application Level Runtime Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a requirement where i need perform some action(execute set of code) on occurrence of runtime exception inside an application,the runtime exception can happen in any point of application,I am searching a solution which can implemented at single place rather then regular way of writing error handle code in each catch block

Answer (score 1):

In Spring you use `@ControllerAdvice` to handle exception at global scope.

Example:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { NullPointerException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(NullPointerException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "null pointer", 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, request);
    }
}
```

You can find many examples around the internet.